# How powershell calls the azure API while uploading/downloading data to & from storage

Tags: security, powershell, azure

When I'm using the azure powershell, I just give the storage account name and the key. Does anyone know how internally the powershell calls the Azure APIs.

And I also have a question that how secure is the data transferred through powershell. If yes, what is the concept underneath it. And if no, how can I secure the transferring pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik Azure PowerShell uses Azure REST APIs under the hood.

The upload of vhd is secure by default. You can't specify additional security objects during upload that i know of.

On the other hand you can always encrypt the data inside vhd that you are uploading, as an additional security measure.

Comment: I'm uploading some highly secured information to blob.. So can you please share me any article that says the data is secured while uploading through powershell.. and also the powershell internal process of uploading files in detail

Comment: I don't believe there are any documents/links for this. I came to know about this in a training. But you can verify this by opening Fiddler while performing an operation via PowerShell. For every command, the request tunnels through `management.azure.com:443`. You can also see that every request also acquires token for the current tenant as well.

Comment: You can access the source code for the PowerShell cmdlets on github, blob upload is here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/dev/src/Storage/Commands.Storage/Blob/Cmdlet/SetAzureStorageBlobContent.cs